# HTTP Live Streaming player behavior

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, audiovideoplayback

I am working on a player playing the HLS Live content. So, it will reloads .m3u8 index file of the test link periodically.

e.g. the player reloaded 01.m3u8 index file.

```
(01.m3u8 - #1)

       0.ts---the player tried to download this 100.ts file first.
       1.ts---
       2.ts
       3.ts
```

Then, it tried to download 0.ts file.

However, the network bandwidth was not enough to download this 0.ts file fast.

It took almost 24 seconds for one TS to download. So, it has reloaded 02.m3u8 index file again.

```
(01.m3u8 - #2)
       2.ts---the player tried to download 102.ts file first.
       3.ts
       4.ts
       5.ts
```

However, the player couldn’t find 1.ts file in the index file. Because, the index file was updated by the server before the player downloads 1.ts file. Therefore, the player tried to download 2.ts file instead of 1.ts file.

This means the player lost the stream data of 20 seconds. So, is this behavior inline with the specs as its seems confusing??

I think it should update the m3u8 starting by 1.ts and not 2.ts. OR how it has been decided.

Can anybody give suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The spec allows severs to remove URI's from the start of the playlist as long as the playlist is still at least three times the target duration. (section 6.2.2 of draft-pantos-http-livestreaming-08)

> The server MUST NOT remove a media URL specifying a segment from the Playlist file if the duration of the Playlist file minus the duration of the segment is less than three times the target duration.

So as long as the playlist contains 4 segments with only minor variations in length this seem to be a valid behavior. For a live stream I would expect the server to remove segments from the stream at the same speed as it adds segments. So with 10 seconds segments I find it reasonable that it removes 2 segments while you spend 24 seconds downloading a single segment.

Answer (score 0):

It has done the right thing. To solve the issue you are facing

Either you should know your network bandwidth and encode accordingly if you want only 1 bitrate [useful for closed & controlled environments]

OR

encode in multiple bandwidths and set up your m3u8s with the multiple bitrates and ensure you give the lowest one as the first entry and HLS will adapt accordingly. Within a couple of segments it will reach the target bandwidth. That is the whole point of HLS actually.